# Remove everything after the pipe

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to remove everything after the pipe but what my code is currently doing is the opposite, it is removing everything before the pipe. I want to remove everything after the pipe including if there is white space. Here is the code what i have tried:

```
DropDownList WPC1 = DV_InputForm.FindControl("ddl_WPC") as DropDownList;
string WPC_Selected = WPC1.SelectedValue;
string WPC = WPC_Selected.Substring(WPC_Selected.LastIndexOf("|") + 1);
```

Comment: `Substring` takes an index from where to start, not what to chop off.  You want to pass in two parameters: 0 to start, and then the index of the pipe character.

Comment: `string WPC = WPC_Selected.Substring(0,WPC_Selected.LastIndexOf("|"));`

Comment: string WPC = WPC_Selected.Substring(WPC_Selected.IndexOf("|")+1, (WPC_Selected.Length - WPC_Selected.IndexOf("|")-1));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must start from `0` index and move till the index of pipe sign.

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of Substring Method.

```
string WPC_Selected = "abc|def";
string WPC = WPC_Selected.Substring(0, WPC_Selected.LastIndexOf("|")); //abc
string WPC1 = WPC_Selected.Substring(0, WPC_Selected.LastIndexOf("|") + 1); //abc|
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove a substring from a string you should use [`String.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it increases readability because your intent is more clear:

```
string WPC = WPC_Selected.Remove(WPC_Selected.LastIndexOf("|") + 1);
```

This returns an empty string if there is no pipe inside. If you want to take the complete string in this case you have to check if `LastIndexOf("|") >= 0` first.

Answer (score 1):

Please  try it

```
DropDownList WPC1 = DV_InputForm.FindControl("ddl_WPC") as DropDownList;
string WPC_Selected = WPC1.SelectedValue;
string WPC = WPC_Selected.Split("|").Lenght>0?WPC_Selected.Split("|")[0].Trim():string.Empty;
```

Comment: what if the first part has a pipe?

Answer (score 0):

Just one line:

```
string WPC = WPC_Selected.Substring(WPC_Selected.IndexOf("|")+1, (WPC_Selected.Length - WPC_Selected.IndexOf("|")-1));
```